# Design Bug: Inconsistent Capitalisation: "featured"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Stop the presses! Roll back the commit! There is an inconsistency in capitalisation!

> [image]

"featured" should be "Featured".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed on live server.